# How to use Brackets with Modern Pages as Wiki?

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I'm starting a new SharePoint site. I have enjoyed the functionality of the Wiki pages in the past where you could use double brackets "[[Page Name Here]]" to create new pages or reference existing ones.

The problem is that with Wiki pages, they don't inherit the navigation of the modern team site.

Is there any way to achieve this ease-of-use, but sticking with modern pages?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I found this which might help.

It looks like you can just add a text web part and it will support the [[]] functionality.

Source:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/publishing-sites-classic-to-modern-experience

Relevant text:
Wiki pages are a content type available in publishing sites, but they are not available in communication sites. However, you can create modern pages using either a Text web part or Markdown web part to cover many of the same scenarios as Wiki pages. Note that Wiki syntax is not available in a Text web part, with the exception of adding a hyperlink with the use of brackets “[[”.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the bracket syntax did work on my migrated classic Wiki Pages albeit a bit glitchy.

You type "[[" and some text and nothing happens.  But when you delete a character the menu pops up.  Thus "[[Home", del, "[[Hom" does the trick.  It's odd but at least workable.

Furthermore, if you type out the whole name in opened/closed double brackets it figures out the appropriate hyperlink.  The point here is the interactive popup is superfluous to the functionality.

I got this same behavior in modern pages (under Site Pages) as well.